# Насколько строки похожи

Tags: алгоритм, строки

Делаю модерацию сообщений в чате. Нужно выяснить, насколько сообщение похоже на то, которое юзер отправил ранее.

Например:

`сколько это может продолжаться` и `cкoлькo этo мoжeт прoдoлжaтьcя` выглядят идентично, однако, во втором случае буквы `o, a, e, c` и подобные заменены на аналогичные из другого языка.

А также другой пример:

`моя служба никогда не закончится` и `моя служба не скоро закончится` по сути, один и тот же смысл, только заменено одно слово.

Короче говоря, мне нужно каким-либо образом проверить, аналогичное сообщение отправил юзер, или нет. Пока думаю над получение процента схожести. Например, если сообщения совпадают на 80% - выполнить действие.

И вопрос состоит в том, как должен выглядеть алгоритм нахождения процента схожести сообщений?

Comment: [Алгоритм шинглов](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC_%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2)

Comment: @AK этот алгоритм рассчитан на обработку и сравнение достаточно объемных текстов. Для чата, мне кажется, он вряд ли применим.

Comment: первый случай (буквы с одинаковым глифом но разными кодами) можно решить путем ручного сравнения, при котором игнорируется различие кодов при совпадении глифа (словарь кодов с совпадающими глифами придется составлять самостоятельно или поискать в сети).  Плюс расстояние Левенштейна для обнаружения опечаток или исправления оных. А вот со смысловой заменой, как во втором примере, это уже интересный вопрос.

Comment: @rdorn, не увидел Ваш коммент, я по сути, повторил, то что Вы писали ранее.

Comment: Какая конечная цель - удалять дубликаты / определять подлинность польователя / что-то еще?

Answer (score 3):

В теории, можно посмотреть на алгоритм расстояния Damerau-Levenshtein, но все равно, потребуется предобработка, т.к. его результат для ситуации из

> сколько это может продолжаться и cкoлькo этo мoжeт прoдoлжaтьcя выглядят идентично, однако, во втором случае буквы o, a, e, c и подобные заменены на аналогичные из другого языка.

будет некорректным для Вас. Вы можете сделать замену и потом вычислить дистанцию по предложенному алгоритму.

Не уверен, что предложенный алгоритм шинглов будет работать лучше - все же, без предобработки (замены "похожих" букв, как минимум) он выдаст разные хэши. Но, тут стоит проверить.

P.S. можно посмотреть вот эту библиотеку, как стартовую точку - https://github.com/feature23/StringSimilarity.NET

P.S. @rdorn выше описал ранее тоже самое